# Positioning dropdown menu on the other side of parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a main nav bar that goes to the right of header, and its drop-downs are appearing right bellow it (first `<li>` has `position: relative;` and `<ul>` bellow it is `postion: absolute;` to it), and it looks like on attached photo.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/F1Jno7n.jpg]

Problem is that i want that drop-down menu to stretch 1100px (which is the width of container below) and to go to the left. You can check the photo to see what I mean.
I tried to accomplish this, but im stuck and don't have any idea where what else to do. Applying any other position to `<ul>` doesn't help, page gets messed up

Any advices?

**CSS**

```
.sf-menu li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

#SideCategoryList li ul, #SideCategoryList .sf-menu li ul {
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 41px;
    width: 1100px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="SideCategoryListFlyout">

    <ul class="sf-menu sf-vertical sf-js-enabled">

        <li>
            <a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">Menu Link 1<span class="sf-sub-indicator">»</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the lists `<ul>` `<li>`have default styles like margin and padding.

everything you are missing is:

```
* {
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vGtQe/1/

or if you just want to reset those default settings to ul li

```
ul, ul li {
    margin:0;padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vGtQe/2/

probably you are looking for something like:
http://jsfiddle.net/vGtQe/3/

there are a few changes made but it may helps you

Comment: Thank you Caramba for ur help, but im afraid that this isnt it (my bad, i should provide more code and better "mockup").Here is a direct link, do you have any advices? http://tinyurl.com/dropdownfullwidth

Comment: @Mariola sorry I just had a short look at it but there are a few things going wrong. If you use float you should also use clearings (google: clear floats). like what it is you could fix it with position:absolute;left:-800px; or something like that but that's not nice at all. to make it nice to you should change the markup

Answer (score 0):

Try to `position: fixed;` on the full width ul

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jd7qW/